# Difference in amperage at the plug vs at the source (three-phase wye, 120 V and 208 V loads)

Tags: power, current, ac, three-phase

I'm trying to understand the difference between how my work calculates power at the load vs how we calculate the sum at the source.

We run temporary power and plug in several hundred industrial devices, some 120 V, and some 208 V.

When we calculate how much power we need to get from the location, we sum up the watts and divide by (120 V × √3). This gives us the amperage on the standard three-phase wye service, so we can order a 100 A, 200 A, or 400 A three-phase service accordingly.

Then, at the load side, we do watts / volts to see how many devices we can plug in before the breaker trips.

The question is: Are we doing it right? Why is it 1000 W / (120 V × √3) when summing amperage at the source but 1000 W / 120 V at the load?

Once we have a final plan in place, we also sum the watts per phase, divide by (120 V × sin(120)) to give us the actual per-phase amperage, as we are never guaranteed to be balanced. We try, but it isn't always possible.

As a note, power factor and other variables don't factor in to our quick calcs. We always use three-phase 120 V services with a neutral, and the devices are either hot-to-neutral 120 V or hot-hot 208 V.